# Lie Derivative of Vector Fields, identification question

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, lie-derivative

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $V,W$ smooth vector fields on $M$. If $\theta:\mathcal{D}\to M$ denotes the flow of $V$, where $\mathcal{D}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}\times M$. The Lie Derivative of $W$ along $V$ at $p$ is given by the following

$$
(\mathcal{L}_V W)_p = \dfrac{d}{dt}\biggr|_{t=0} d(\theta_{-t}(p))(W_{\theta_{t}(p)}) = \lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{d(\theta_{-t}(p))(W_{\theta_t(p)})-W_p}{t}
$$

The tangent space at $p$ is a vector space, so $T_pM$ is endowed with a smooth structure. If we define $X(t) = d(\theta_{-t}(p))(W_{\theta_t(p)})$, this is a curve $X:(-\varepsilon,+\varepsilon)\to T_pM$ starting at $W_p$, since $X(0)=W_p$. The left hand side becomes

$$
(\mathcal{L}_V W)_p = \dfrac{d}{dt}\biggr\vert_{t=0}X(t) = X'(0)\in T_{W_p}(T_pM)
$$

While the right hand side looks like some kind of Frechet derivative on $T_pM$. My question is, what is the highlighted part trying to say? This is from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highlighted part explains why can you switch order of derivative and $d\theta$. Next it argues that this is required result.

\begin{align}
\frac d {ds}\bigg|_{s=0} d(\theta_{-t_0}) &\circ d(\theta_{-s})(W_{\theta_s(\theta_{t_0}(p))}) \\
&= \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{
d(\theta_{-t_0}) \circ d(\theta_{-s})(W_{\theta_s(\theta_{t_0}(p))})- d(\theta_{-t_0})(W_{\theta_{t_0}(p)})}{s} \\
&= \lim_{s\to 0} 
d(\theta_{-t_0}) \left(\frac{d(\theta_{-s})(W_{\theta_s(\theta_{t_0}(p))})- W_{\theta_{t_0}(p)}}{s}\right) \\
&= 
d(\theta_{-t_0}) \left(\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{d(\theta_{-s})(W_{\theta_s(\theta_{t_0}(p))})- W_{\theta_{t_0}(p)}}{s}\right) \\
&= 
d(\theta_{-t_0})( (\mathcal{L}_V W)_{\theta_{t_0}(p)}) \\
\end{align}

In second equality we used linearity of $d \theta_{-t_0}$. Next independence $d \theta_{-t_0}$ of $s$ **and** continuity of linear function on finite dimensional space (not emphasized by author) allows third equality. Final equality is definition of Lie derivative, where second vector field is $p \mapsto W_{\theta_{t_0}(p)}$. Since $\theta_{t_0}$ is locally a diffeomorphism, it is the same as $ (\mathcal{L}_V W)_{\theta_{t_0}(p)}$.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the Lie Derivative $(\mathcal{L}_V W)_p$ *defined* as the Frechet derivative of the following at $t=0$?

$$
t\mapsto d(\theta_{-t})_{\theta_t(p)}(W_{\theta_t(p)})
$$

Because the argument in Proposition 9.41 hints as the expression $X'(t_0)$ being some kind of 'velocity of curves' on the vector space $T_p M$. I say this because in Proposition 22.14 (which is not included in the main post), Lee writes

$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\biggr\vert_{t=t_0}(\psi^*_{t,t_0}f)(p) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\biggr\vert_{t=t_0}f(\psi(t,t_0,p))
$$

Comment: which implies the derivation 

$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\biggr\vert_{t=t_0}
$$

has been pushed forward, and we view $(\psi^*_{t,t_0}f)(p)$ as a curve in some vector space parametrized by $t$. However, shouldn't the second term be

$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\biggr\vert_{(t_0,t_0,p)} f(\psi(t,t_0,p))
$$


 I have included the relevant material in the main post.